# android scroll and see details like whatsup

Tags: android, android-scrollview, whatsapp

Place some icon like down arrow so that user can know there is some details are shown below in android.

[image]

after scrolled page end, scroll arrow will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 scrollView1.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

         public void onScrollChanged() {

           int scrollViewHeight = scrollView1.getChildAt(0).getHeight();


           Log.e("scrollVIEW_height", "SCROLL" + scrollViewHeight);

           double size = 0;

           DisplayMetrics dm = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

           float screenWidth = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi;

           float screenHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi;

           float i = dm.heightPixels;

           Log.e("height in i", "" + i);

           double heightininch = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenHeight, 2));

           Log.e("height in inch", "" + heightininch);

           size = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(screenWidth, 2) + Math.pow(screenHeight, 2));

           Log.e("screen", "" + size);

           if (size >= 6) {

             if (scrollViewHeight >= (int)i) {

               DownIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

               // TopIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

             }
           }
        }
    });
```